# I want to implement custom Android appliction physical keyboard keys, do I need to modify qwerty.kl file or how to add a new keyboard mapping?

Tags: java, android, api, keyboard

In order to implement a keyboard remapping graphical tool for a specific terminal’s keyboard, the KeyboardManager returns the keyboard layout as a table of scan codes

Answer (score 0):

You should never modify qwerty.kl (and you should never have to). Or Generic.kl. There should be a specific keylayout file for the device you are trying to map (see [here](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/input/key-layout-files.html)). If it has a driver, it should have a keylayout file with the Vendor/Product or Vendor/Product/Version style name. Otherwise, it should use the device name.

Also, be aware that there are [key character map files](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/input/key-character-map-files.html) that use a similar naming convention.

Modifying the keyboard access could easily screw things up, so I hope you have some other input access. Make backups before you do anything.